# Why is my GRUB displaying so many options?

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, windows-8

I have Ubuntu in dual boot alongside the original W8 install.
My grub shows a ton of options. The first one loads Ubuntu alright. In the past I tried loading w8 (which I hardly ever use) and after loading W8 and restating the machine it somehow managed to get grub disabled. Which option loads W8, and is there a way to clean up grub to show only relevant options?

[image]

Comment: That's normal, except all the weird "EFI" options and "System setup", and the double Windows (it shows only Windows Recovery Environment in 15.10 and earlier, on before-alpha of 16.04 it shows Windows 10.) And "Windows UEFI bkpbootmgfw.efi" AND "Windows Boot UEFI loader" and finally, "Previous Linux versions" which i never saw...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I edit my Grub bootloader entries (Hide, Rename, Remove)? Preferably doing it manually, and not with a program](http://askubuntu.com/questions/81660/how-can-i-edit-my-grub-bootloader-entries-hide-rename-remove-preferably-doi)

Comment: @StarOS under "Previous versions" you have the options to boot older kernels, in case the current one doesn't work properly (e.g. after a kernel update)

Comment: @the_Seppi It's not a duplicate, it's asking why are there so many options (50% of them i have no clue what it is), and i didn't know the previous thing.

Comment: Those entries are from Boot-Repair. Boot-Repair creates a 25_custom  grub for any .efi files found in the ESP - efi system partition. Since HP has tons of recovery/repair .efi files you get a long list. Some other vendors have those files in a hidden efi boot partition that they can access if needed. You can probably delete all of 25_custom or edit out most entries. Just like this except use 25_custom, not 40_custom: http://askubuntu.com/questions/659528/grub-menu-with-windows-10-and-ubuntu-14-04/659910#659910

Comment: @oldfred: Your comment would make a good answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To boot Windows 8, you need to select

```
Windows 8 (loader) (on /dev/sda4)
```

---

I understand that you want to tidy up the menu. This can be done most easily with the program `grub-customizer`. It's available from  [ppa:danielrichter2007/grub-customizer [image: Launchpad logo]](https://launchpad.net/~danielrichter2007/+archive/grub-customizer) ([Click here for instructions on using PPAs.](https://askubuntu.com/q/4983))

So to install it on your Ubuntu system, run the following commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:danielrichter2007/grub-customizer
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install grub-customizer
```

Then, launch `grub-customizer`. After it has loaded your configuration and detected all locally installed bootable stuff, you should see a list like this:

[image: grub-customizer screenshot]

You can rename items by double-clicking them.
To create submenus (folders) to group several similar menu points to one entry, select all items you want to group and chose <kbd>Create submenu</kbd> from the right-click context menu or the <kbd>Edit</kbd> menu.

Changes will not be applied until you click the <kbd>Save</kbd> button, or close the window and chose <kbd>Save & Exit</kbd> from the appearing dialogue.