# GRUB Menuentry One GUI Boot & One Console

Tags: boot, grub2, xorg, console

I want two menuentrys in grub
One to boot ubuntu into textmode to actually function as a server (running everything like apache2 except all X related things to save memory and CPU usage)
And one to boot into X to use normal applications.

Thanks in advance,
Martin

Comment: Uncomment #GRUB_TERMINAL=console from /etc/default/grub You also then can add a standard boot stanza to 40_custom. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MaintenanceFreeCustomGrub2Screen  this was to copy a Windows boot stanza but you do same thing: http://askubuntu.com/questions/659528/grub-menu-with-windows-10-and-ubuntu-14-04/659910#659910