# How do I stop Grub from scanning particular disks

Tags: dual-boot, grub2

I have seen posts about stopping the os_prober from finding any disk when doing a grub update by deleting the os_prober.  However, I have a dual boot and want grub to see both my Ubuntu and Windows 10 partitions on my NVME drive, but I don't want it to scan my 10TB backup disk looking for a partition.

Thoughts?

Thank you in advance.

Paul

Answer (score 0):

I have many installs, some obsolete and lots of partitions, but only 1TB. First thing I do is turn off os-prober and add only the boot stanza's I want into 40_custom. I include 40_custom in my backups.

```
sudo cp -a /boot/grub/grub.cfg /boot/grub/grub.cfg.backup
sudoedit /etc/default/grub
```

then add

```
GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER=true
sudo update-grub
```

Then we copy Windows boot stanza from grub backup to 40_custom. Use your editor, example is with gedit. You can open backup read only, but need sudo to open 40_custom.

```
gedit /boot/grub/grub.cfg
sudo nano -B /etc/grub.d/40_custom
sudo update-grub
```

Similar:

[Grub menu with Windows 10 and Ubuntu 14.04](http://askubuntu.com/questions/659528/grub-menu-with-windows-10-and-ubuntu-14-04/659910#659910)

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MaintenanceFreeCustomGrub2Screen

Mega-Thead, lots of examples of boot stanzas, best to start at end for latest info.

https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2076205

https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2076205&page=54&p=13787835#post13787835

[How to update grub on a dual boot machine?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/848119/how-to-update-grub-on-a-dual-boot-machine/848614#848614)