# Problem using "GRUB_OS_PROBER_SKIP_LIST" to prevent scanning of a specific drive in a multiboot system with separate drives

Tags: dual-boot, grub2

I have a multiboot system (Windows 10, Ubuntu + other distributions each on their own dedicated disk) installed in UEFI mode. The Grub bootloader is installed in the Linux drive ESP partition.
Wanting to delete the Windows 10 menu entry from Grub menu I thought about adding the parameter "GRUB_OS_PROBER_SKIP_LIST" in the /etc/default/grub file.
After reading several discussions about it and the Grub manual:
"‘GRUB_OS_PROBER_SKIP_LIST’
List of space-separated FS UUIDs of filesystems to be ignored from os-prober output. For efi chainloaders it’s <UUID@<EFI_FILE>"
I tried with:

```
GRUB_OS_PROBER_SKIP_LIST="58EE-F18B@/dev/nvme0n1p2"
```

or:

```
GRUB_OS_PROBER_SKIP_LIST="58EE-F18B@/dev/nvme0n1p2/efi/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi"
```

but it didn't work and every time after updating Grub the Windows 10 menu entry the windows 10 menu entry is still there:

```
Trovato Windows Boot Manager su /dev/nvme0n1p2@/efi/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
```

Where am I doing wrong?

Comment: I just turn off os-prober in /etc/default/grub. Add this line `GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER=true` I backup my grub.cfg, can if I want add some boot stanzas into 40_custom. Any grub update is a lot quicker as it does not have to scan system and with multiple installs on my system takes a while. After any grub change run `sudo update-grub`. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/CustomMenus & https://askubuntu.com/questions/1332570/how-do-i-stop-grub-from-scanning-particular-disks/1332664#1332664

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
GRUB_OS_PROBER_SKIP_LIST="58EE-F18B@/efi/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi"
```

istead of

```
GRUB_OS_PROBER_SKIP_LIST="58EE-F18B@/dev/nvme0n1p2/efi/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi"
```

Generating new grub config file will notify you with something like

```
Skipped Windows Boot Manager on /dev/sda1@/efi/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi by user request.
```