# How to delete a partition for a dual-boot Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: system-installation, software-installation, hard-drive, windows-10

I have successfully installed Ubuntu on my PC with dual boot alongside Windows 10. However, I noticed that there are two partitions for Windows 10 when I start my PC.

[Screenshot of Start Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jvc4K.jpg)

How can I remove one of them without affecting my installations or the integrity of my HDD.

Comment: UEFI boot entries aren't partitions.

Comment: @ChanganAuto Forgive my ignorance. How do I remove one of the dev/sda?

Comment: Not that either! Do you really want to remove an entire physical drive? I don't think so. Honestly, I suggest you keep things as they are because at least one of them boots Windows, right? You have tested it already, right? Of course, there are tools to cleanup EFI but one wrong move and the result is one or both OSes unbootable. You may try running `sudo update-grub` in Ubuntu. IF it stays the same then please edit your question and post the results of `efibootmgr -v`

Comment: More info: https://www.linuxbabe.com/command-line/how-to-use-linux-efibootmgr-examples

Comment: That looks more like BIOS/MBR configuration. And Windows has a Boot partition with boot files. Some users do not know those files are essential to boot & delete that partition. Boot-repair and maybe  other tools then copy the boot files as backup into main or c: "drive" partition. Then grub finds two sets of boot files as it just looks for files not boot flag, like Windows does. if you really only want one entry, copy one entry into 40_custom & turn off os-prober. https://askubuntu.com/questions/659528/grub-menu-with-windows-10-and-ubuntu-14-04/659910#659910