# Ubuntu 22.04 + Windows 10 (dual boot): GRUB not showing and not

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi, windows-10

After installing Ubuntu 22.04 on a machine which already had Windows installed I can only boot into Ubuntu, but not Windows anymore.

Here is what I did:

- installed Ubuntu 22.04 from here: https://ubuntu.com/download/desktop
- used Rufus to create a bootable USB drive in Windows
- booted from the USB drive to install Ubuntu

I already tried boot-repair, here is the Boot-Info Summary: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/ywwXxswTqg/

I can see the following text quickly before Ubuntu starts (not sure if it's related or if it helps though):
[image: error while booting]

I also checked the Windows Boot Loader is before ubuntu in my UEFI settings.

How can I boot into Windows again? It would be nice if I got the option to choose what OS to boot (which is what GRUB is for from what I understand). If that's not possible I would at least like to boot into Windows again like before installing Ubuntu.

Comment: update: I was able to boot into windows by setting the default OS to boot to Windows using boot-repair. But now only Windows boots without the option to select the OS.

Comment: you need to go into Ubuntu, run `sudo os-prober` and then `sudo update-grub`, see https://askubuntu.com/questions/1425637/how-can-i-add-windows-11-to-grub-menu/1425655#1425655

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I add Windows 11 to grub menu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1425637/how-can-i-add-windows-11-to-grub-menu)

Comment: If you looks at UEFI entry: Boot0012* Windows Boot Manager it is booting: \EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi  It should be booting a Windows boot file. You had to manually change that, as that is not normal (anymore).  `sudo efibootmgr -c -L "Windows Boot Manager" -l "\EFI\Microsoft\Boot\bootmgfw.efi" -d /dev/sda -p 2` See `man efibootmgr`

Comment: @oldfred 's answer is true, but it still didn't solve my problem. Turned out it was an issue with grub itself. [This post](https://medium.com/@leijerry888/get-grub-menu-back-after-installing-ubuntu-20-04-alongside-windows-dab5de5afc37) did the trick for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out the Grub menu didn't show up because of an issue with Grub itself. I had to modify Grub as described in [this post](https://medium.com/@leijerry888/get-grub-menu-back-after-installing-ubuntu-20-04-alongside-windows-dab5de5afc37):

```
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=menu
GRUB_TERMINAL=console
```