# Windows/Ubuntu Dual-Boot - Adding Windows UEFI After Install

Tags: dual-boot, grub2

A few months ago, I had Pop!_OS installed on my third SSD (*I have 3 SSDs: 250GB-Windows 2TB-Storage 480GB-Linux*). I decided to give Ubuntu another go, but I've had some problems with this before, so I shut down my system and unplugged all but my Linux SSD to clean install Ubuntu.

After the successful installation I plugged my SSDs back in and I've been running it like this for quite some time now. But it is getting a bit annoying to enter my BIOS every time I want to select what OS to boot into.

I am wondering if there's a way to add my Windows UEFI to the Ubuntu "boot menu" thing? I think it's called grub.
I'm still new to the whole Linux environment so I haven't learned enough to understand certain things. So, I ask for comprehensive solutions for this, basically a "dumbed down" version.

Thank you!

Comment: If your Ubuntu install runs grub, simply run sudo update-grub and Windows might be picked up. If not, ensure that /etc/default/grub.d does not have the  GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER=ture option set.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and clarify your setup: i) where is Ubuntu installed and, if you know this, where is Ubuntu's bootloader installed? ii) What are these SSDs, why are they relevant? How does the system use them? Which of the installed systems uses them? Are any of the systems installed there? iii) What is it you currently do in your BIOS that you no longer want to do? Are you changing boot orders?

Comment: If Windows fast startup/hibernation is on or bitlocker is on, then grub may not boot the Windows entry that os-prober finds. ubfan1 has typo, it is =true for os-prober setting that you may need to change to =false.  I prefer to have os-prober off & add my own boot entries into 40_custom. First time I just copied from grub.cfg before turning os-prober off. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1425637/how-can-i-add-windows-11-to-grub-menu & https://askubuntu.com/questions/848119/how-to-update-grub-on-a-dual-boot-machine

Comment: Thank you for the information @oldfred I will look into this as soon as I can and update on how it went.