Kubuntu default kernal
I'm currently dual booting Kubuntu and Windows 11 on my Microsoft Surface Pro 8. I've just wiped the Kubuntu partition and re-imaged it from scratch after seeing multiple claims that the Grub Customizer app I'd used previously can be problematic, and have used some basic terminal edits to achieve some of what I had done before. It's not as customised as it was, but is getting the job done, however I've hit a snag and hoping someone can help
On the fresh install, I've used the below to load the grub config
sudoedit /ect/default/grub
And I've edited the following lines to set the resolution, boot timeout, and default boot option of my Windows partition (it's a family computer so I need it to auto boot to Windows when my wife uses it), these are working as expected
GRUB_DEFAULT=4
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
GRUB_GFXMODE=800x600
Following this, I've also installed this Microsoft Surface kernal to get the touch screen going
https://github.com/linux-surface/linux-surface/wiki/Installation-and-Setup
This seems to have installed properly, however the machine is still booting to the original default kernal when I select the main Kubuntu option in the grub menu. If I go to advanced options and manually select the Surface kernal, it works great, but I'd like to be able to set that as the default Kubuntu Kernal, without changing the default boot setting of Windows. Is this possible?
Also as an aside, is it possible to re-arrange the grub menu items without the grub customizer app? Before I had it set so the Windows partition was the first option, with Kubuntu right below it, so I only had to tap down and enter to load Linux, but now with the default set to index 4 I'm having to scroll all the way to the top of the menu to select Kubuntu. This is a minor inconveinence so not a huge deal, but would be nice if I could still achieve it

Did you run sudo update-grub after your changes? Why 800x600, grub normally tries to use default graphics. Have not seen a special kernel for Surface? You did not post link. You can copy Windows boot stanza into 06_custom. Copy 40_custom to 06_custom and add Windows boot stanza. Grub does scripts in order so then Windows will be first. http://askubuntu.com/questions/659528/grub-menu-with-windows-10-and-ubuntu-14-04/659910#659910  And in this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1425637/how-can-i-add-windows-11-to-grub-menu & https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/CustomMenus

Oh my bad I thought I had included it, I've updated the post with the URL. I actually found a solution in the end, with a bit more googling I figured out how to enable editing the grub.cfg file directly and with some careful cut/copy/paste I was able to re-order the menu items and make the Surface Kernal the one that loads on the top level Kubuntu menu option

You should not directly edit grub.cfg as every kernel, grub & maybe a few other updates run the update-grub creating a new grub.cfg from scripts & settings. Better to change script so update always works the way you want.

Ah OK duly noted, that's a shame, thought I was on to something. What script change are you referring to, is that something I could use to achieve the same result for rearranging the menu and the default kernal?

The comment above on 06_custom with Windows boot stanza. Then that will always be first.

Ah I see now, sorry missed that part earlier, I'll see if I can find those scripts

I created 06_custom as below, but update-grub tells me there's a syntax error, what am I doing wrong here?
#!/bin/sh
exec tail -n +3 $0
This file provides an easy way to add custom menu entries.  Simply type the
menu entries you want to add after this comment.  Be careful not to change
the 'exec tail' line above.
menuentry 'Windows 11' --class windows --class os $menuentry_id_option 'osprobe>
insmod part_gpt
insmod fat
search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root C2FE-2D56
chainloader /EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
}

Hard to read in comment, better in question as then can be formatted. But do you have leading { as shown in example in link above? Another example, description can be anything you want. https://askubuntu.com/questions/233687/dual-boot-ubuntu-12-10-on-uefi-along-windows-8-grub-error-cant-find-command Often best to open grub.cfg and just copy entire Windows boot stanza into 06_custom, be sure to include ending } as you must have matching start & end of code stanza or {}

Ah yes lack of formatting is an issue, sorry about that. I thought I had the leading { but looking again maybe I missed it, I had copy/pasted the stanza from the grub.cfg file but maybe I missed a bit, I'll have another look at the example you shared and see if I can figure out what's missing. Many thanks for your input

Grub.cfg.new sometimes shows error line. But I missed a } once and it just said it was at end when it really was in middle.

You were right, I needed to re-format what I'd pulled from grub.cfg, I got it working by comparing to the examples you linked to, thanks again!
